# How do I pass a JSP (HTML) table's row to a servlet?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

This is the code I have:

```
    <table border="2">
<tr>
<th>CourseID</th>
<th>SectionNo</th>
<th>Add Info</th>
</tr>
    <% while(rs.next()){    %>  

        <tr>
            <FORM NAME="actionForm" action="ProfCourseUpdate" method='post'>
            <td> <%=rs.getString("CourseID") %> </td>
            <td> <%=rs.getInt("SectionNo") %> </td>
            <td> <input type="submit" name="ProfCourseUpdate" value="Update Course Info"></td>
            </FORM>
        </tr>

    <% } %>
</table>
```

I'm pulling information from a database and putting them into their respective columns in a table. 
So it looks like:
|Course --- Section --- (Button)|

When I have a user click the submit button I want to be able to pass along the data from the entire row. I've tried hidden input in this way:

```
<td> <%=rs.getString("CourseID") %> </td><td><input type="hidden" name="Course" value="<%rs.getString("CourseID") %>"></td>
```

It just results in some strange table formatting and didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put all the information you want to pass on INPUT (text, hidden) or using a URL to inform that to a servlet.

First, a couple of things you might want to consider:

1. Use only **one** `form` tag in your page instead of using one for each row.
2. Enclose the whole `table` within your `form` tag.

You will end up with something like this:

```
<FORM NAME="actionForm" action="ProfCourseUpdate" method='post'>
<table border="2">
<tr>
    <th>CourseID</th>
    <th>SectionNo</th>
    <th>Add Info</th>
</tr>
<% while(rs.next()){    %>  
<tr>
    <td> <%=rs.getString("CourseID") %> </td>
    <td> <%=rs.getInt("SectionNo") %> </td>
    <td> <input type="submit" name="ProfCourseUpdate" value="Update Course Info"></td>
</tr>
<% } %>
</table>
</FORM>
```

Now, with that all cleared out of the way, you might want to use a different approach. If you want your table for selecting a course/section purpose, you don't even need a form (or a submit button for that matter).

You could replace this:

```
    <td><input type="submit" name="ProfCourseUpdate" value="Update Course Info"></td>
```

With this:

```
    <td><a href="/ProfCourseUpdate?CourseID=<%=rs.getString("CourseID") %>&SectionNo=<%=rs.getInt("SectionNo") %>">Update</a></td>
```

This way, your `ProfCourseUpdate` servlet with receive the two variables needed (`CourseID` and `SectionNo`) to retrieve and update that row.

If you must use a button, you could use the same technique, but encoding `CourseID` and `SectionNo` on value. But I would not recommend it.

Comment: Yes, I tried using hidden input, but it didn't work. How can I create a URL containing unique information for each row?

Comment: Hi geoxile. Looks like you don't have much experience on WEB DEVELOPMENT. Before digging into SERVLET stuff, I would recommend reading about GET and POST methods on a HTML FORM. How do the work, how do they pass information to the server. It will give you a cleaner scenario to start developing software with Servlets and JavaEE technology.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I'm not very experienced. I have tried reading tutorials on JSP but my retention from reading is pretty poor, especially since I find reading dreadful at times, so I find actually working on a project and getting stuck on things is the best way for me to learn. Thanks for all your help.